# I made a very basic scripting language - I want to be able to read output.

Tags: c#, events, stream

I made a very basic scripting language, and in my language there is a command called `print` - or in other words - `print _k` should somehow show `_k` to the user.
I was using `MessageBox.Show` till now but I also want to include a debugger for my language and for other reasons, I want to use a `Stream` or something like it.

Basically, on the main form I wanna have a `TextBox` or something that is somehow connected to a `Stream`, and when (in script, on a different thread) `print something` is called it will raise an event on my form that will write `something` on my `TextBox`.

I used to overcome this problem by sending the `TextBox` object as a parameter, but I want to make it more dynamic (so I could read data in more ways than `TexBox`).

Unfortunately, `Stream` doesn't have any events I can use.
Maybe there is another dynamic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you out:

http://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on building a scripting language; I did that once and it was one of the most fun and productive things I worked on. Your instincts to provide a debugger and to use streams rather than strings or files are good ones.

It is difficult to suggest how to approach you specific problem because you provide no code, so we have to guess. I handled that situation by passing `Stream`s in all APIs, and handled text boxes by converting the textbox text to a `MemoryStream`, and using `StreamReader` in the scripting engine.

As an aside, [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com) had an outstanding series on creating a scripting language called [ConScript](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ConscriptIDE.aspx), complete with an IDE including a debugger. I got a lot of ideas out of that series.

Comment: Thanks, but the person above you gave me a good answer and it works for me. And yes, it was very fun coding it (although I don't think its the best because it's assembly-like - i.e no complex commands like `int i = 2*x + Math.Sqrt(k) + 51`)